# PowerShell: Write-Progress not working with RoboCopy, Workaround?

Tags: powershell, progress-bar, robocopy

I have successfully incorporated `Write-Progress` into my scripts. When my scripts get to any portion where `RoboCopy` is used `Write-Progress` disappears and reappears when `RoboCopy` is complete:

```
Write-Progress -Id 1 -Activity $arg2 -PercentComplete $i -Status $arg1
RoboCopy C:\source C:\destination /MIR
```

I have considered using `Start-Process` to run `Write-Progress` but have had limited success. Any help would be gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to answer my own question. Here is the solution by using `Start-Job`:

```
Write-Progress -Id 1 -Activity $arg2 -PercentComplete $i -Status $arg1
Start-Job { RoboCopy C:\source C:\destination /MIR LOG+:C:\log.txt } > $null
cat C:\log.txt
```

So let me explain. `Start-Job` creates a background job and redirects it's own output to the bit-bucket. Since it's a background job, I'm immediately returned to run more stuff, like cat which spills all the contents of RoboCopy's log file. In the end, it works as it should to begin with. YAY!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect Robocopy takes over the console display buffer to display progress.  Try using the robocopy options `/NP /NJH /NJS`.  You may also need to add `/NS /NC /NFL /NDL`.

Comment: I'll experiment using different options. Thanks again Keith!

Comment: Ok, this works; however all output from RoboCopy is suppressed. I want my cake and eat it too. :)

Comment: Try removing some of the /N* options.  It would be useful to figure out which one (or ones) mess up PowerShell's Write-Progress display.

Comment: I tried all sorts of combinations of the /N* options. Didn't work, however I became more familiar with  RoboCopy and that is a good thing! Thanks again.